# Android 12 expedited job notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-workmanager, foreground-service

After upgrading my phone to Android 12 I started to some unexpected behavior with the expedited work job. That is the code I had:

```
val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>()
    .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest)
```

And also I had the `getForegroundInfo()` overrided to return `ForegroundInfo` instance.

On Android < 12 my work job worked fine: it is long-running and when it got started, the notification was shown in notification trey, and the job was done.

Now, with Android 12 I don't see any notification icon and if I'll turn the screen off, the **job is cancelled exactly in one minute**. And immediately gets relaunched.

If I explicitly call `setForeground()` in `doWork()` method (I don't know what is the difference), it slightly change the behavior: the notification starts to show (not at once for some reason) but it goes away after some time, when the job is still running. The job itself doesn't get cancelled.

What does it all mean? Do I do something wrong? All I want is to launch long-running expedited job with a notification.

**Upd:** I've noticed that the same thing happens when I just create a foreground service. It gets stopped in exactly one minute if I navigate away from the app (so the app is in background). So, it seems that the problem is in a foreground service itself, since android uses it implicitly when an expedited work is started.

Comment: A bit late, but it might be related to undocumented power management optimizations by various OEMs. More details here: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Did you override `getForegroundInfo()` in your Worker class? According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work):

> Any ListenableWorker must implement the getForegroundInfo method if
> you would like to request that the task run as an expedited job

Comment: If he haven't he would have crashed.

Comment: yeah, and it works fine on Android 10, Android 11

Answer (score 0):

> If I explicitly call setForeground() in doWork() method (I don't know
> what is the difference), it slightly change the behavior:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running

ListenableWorker now supports the setForegroundAsync() API, and CoroutineWorker supports a suspending setForeground() API. **These APIs allow developers to specify that this WorkRequest is important (from a user perspective) or long-running.**

> On Android < 12 my work job worked fine: it is long-running and when
> it got started, the notification was shown in notification trey, and
> the job was done.

To maintain backwards compatibility for expedited jobs, WorkManager **might run a foreground service** on platform versions older than Android 12. Foreground services can display a notification to the user.

**When targeting Android 12 or higher, foreground services remain available to you through the corresponding setForeground method.**

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#worker
https://developer.android.com/static/images/guide/background/workmanager_main.svg

Workers don't know whether the work they're doing is expedited or not. But **workers can display a notification on some versions of Android** when a WorkRequest has been expedited.

To enable this, WorkManager provides the getForegroundInfoAsync() method, which you must implement so WorkManager can display a notification to start a ForegroundService for you where necessary.

**Long story short - there is a lot of might, can, etc.** What you need to do is debug the JobScheduler and figure out what exactly is happening and then try to figure out why.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging#use-alb-shell0dumpsys-jobscheduler

- Check what exactly Constraint is satisfied or not.
- What is your Quota and Internet usage(you have an amount in
  milliseconds)
- What is your PowerBucket(you might ask the user to exempt you from
  battery optimization)
- History of executed jobs

Comment: Actually, the main question: why the job can be canceled and why notification goes away after some short time? I even removed `setExpedited` making it a long-running job. Still the notification goes away after a minute or two.

Comment: I've noticed that the same thing happens when I just create a foreground service. It gets stopped in exactly one minute if I navigate away from the app (so the app is in background).